# НЕ или НИ одной?

Tags: грамматика, не-или-ни

Какую частицу выбрать? НЕ или НИ?

*Не было уже не одной двойки. Так и не получила не одной пятерки.*

Answer (score 2):

В первом предложении это зависит от вкладываемого смысла. Во втором предложении (на второй позиции) - только *усилительная* частица **ни**:

> Чернила испарялись медленно, но верно. **Не** было уже **не** одной двойки. 
>   Из дневника исчезла **ещё и** вчерашняя тройка.
>
> Стала учиться лучше. **Не** было уже **ни** одной двойки. Так и **не** получила **ни**
>   одной пятерки.

"**Не** одной" имеет значение "*не только (этой)*", "**ни** одной" - "*ни сколько, ни в каком количестве*".

Comment: В первом случае, мне кажется, лучше так: "Не было уже не одной _(только)_ двойки - из дневника исчезла ещё и вчерашняя тройка". А то воспринимается как ошибка.

Comment: Я использовал предложение в оригинале (специально не трогая его). В изолированном виде оно может восприниматься как ошибка, и лишь потому, что _редкий контекст_ может придать ему смысл. Но такой контекст нашёлся.

Answer (score 1):

В обоих случаях это усиление отрицания, поэтому используется частица ***ни***.

Справочник В. Лопатина объясняет:

> Основная функция частицы ни — усиление отрицания. ...
>
> 1. Одиночная частица ***ни*** выступает перед словами *один* и (реже) *единый*, которые могут быть и подразумеваемыми, напр.: *За несколько дней он не
>    увидел ни одного человека.*