# Как правильно использовать в данном предложении частицы "не" и "ни"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, частица-не

"Не одна ссылка не допускается". Или же... "Ни одна ссылка не допускается"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [НЕ или НИ одной?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437496/%d0%9d%d0%95-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9d%d0%98-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 2):

Две частицы НЕ бывает, только если это двойное отрицание = положительный результат: Нельзя не видеть = нужно видеть. У Вас отрицание "не допускается", значит, "ни одна" - усиление.

Верен 2-й вариант: ***Ни** одна ссылка не допускается.*